Add Dynamic Url to a New Relic Dashboard
I'm currently working on add graph widget to a new relic dashboard . Dashboard query contains dynamic parameters . I need to get data for all requests for that API call . My query is below
Not working
SELECT average(newrelic.timeslice.value) * 1000 AS Average External API Calls per Second FROM Metric WHERE metricTimesliceName = 'External/api.abc.com/{type}/api/Import/bookid/{bookid}/user/{userId}' AND entity.guid = 'CVBFBFFNHGFDDDXXBJbBVCSRJJMGDD' SINCE 10 minutes AGO TIMESERIES
Dashoboard is generating for query without dynamic parts.
Working NQL query
SELECT average(newrelic.timeslice.value) * 1000 AS Average External API Calls per Second FROM Metric WHERE metricTimesliceName = 'External/api.abc.com/all' AND entity.guid = 'CVBFBFFNHGFDDDXXBJbBVCSRJJMGDD' SINCE 10 minutes AGO TIMESERIES.
Appreciate if you can help me to find out what needs be modified in not working query. Thanks

have you tried using template variables for a dynamic dashboard?
here is the official documentation - https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/explore-query-data/dashboards/dashboard-template-variables/
you can basically create a template variable with a simple NRQL and use it to pass that in your dashboard query. Hope that helps!
